# What is it with Deadpool and chimichangas?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

So the recent turning of Captain America into a Hydra agent prompted some [interesting Internet commentary](https://twitter.com/gmskarka/status/736238782064820225)

Spoiler tag for language

> [image: Meme template starting with the original Captain America saying "Hail Hydra". It has been altered 4 times for: Batman "I shot my parents.", Spider-Man "Fuck responsibility.", Daredeveil "I could see the whole time.", Deadpool "I hate chimichangas."]

So I get the first four, but... Deadpool and chimichangas? I'm not an avid comic reader but I feel like I'm in the dark there. What's the connection?

Comment: Haha for real. For deadpool chimichangas and and the NTS it's pizza.

Comment: NTS? Do you mean TMNTs?

Comment: So you spoiler tag a word that every has seen thousands of times already, but you don't spoiler tag the spoilers for a movie unrelated to the title of your thread. Thanks...

Comment: chimichangas are awesome. And deadpool also thinks so. But since the joke of this meme is that everyone is suddenly not who they've always been, he hates chimichangas.
mmm... Chimichangas.

Comment: So, 5 people agreed that there should be an extra spoiler tag here, but none of them clicked [edit] and added one. I'd add one now, but this has got to be about the most talked-about plotline of the last decade, so ... meh. Also, pretty sure there's no movie involving this (yet).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### In light of the meme you provided, the goal of the meme was to show characters in diametric opposition to to ideals they previously espoused.

> This was done in protest to the recent revelation that Captain America was secretly an operative of Hydra, in *Captain America: Steve Rogers* #1.

As such, the other images lampoon the idea further by having each hero espouse something equally contradictory.

> [image: Steve with a stern face wielding his shield in a more traditional knight style runs at the camera saying "Hail Hydra." a stern faced blonde woman walks behind him]

- Batman shoots his parents - instead of his parents being shot by a criminal
- Spider-Man chooses to ignore responsibility - instead of his trademark statement taught to him by his uncle Ben - with great power comes great responsibility.
- Daredevil, famed blind superhero - reveals he can see the whole time. This is not quite the subversion of the meme the writer was trying to make but okay, we'll allow it.
- Deadpool reveals he hates chimichangas - this is problematic because we already know he hates chimichangas, he has already admitted this. He loves the sound, the way it feels in his sanity-challenged mentality.

  [image: Deadpool leaves Barat's loft and heads for a restaurant/cafe; he sits down and orders an enchilada from the waiter; he says to himself that he doesn't really like eating chimichangas but likes saying it chimichangas]

  *from *Cable and Deadpool* #13*
- But we do know Deadpool does love certain foods and perhaps this meme would have worked better if he said, for example how much he loathes pancakes. This image reveals an absolute love of them...

  [image: Deadpool wears an apron and chef hat, he has a spatula in his right hand and a plate in his left, pancakes are falling off of the plate onto a pile of thousands of them, he says "I love the smell of 372,844 pancakes in the morning. Smells like victory."]
- His love of tacos is also well known if not as abundantly drawn:

  [image: Deadpool asks what can make the night even more awesome, "Tacos?" "YES!!", four fists punch in the air, one firing a pistol, they all shout "TACOS!"]

What we can learn from this is that often people make memes without a true understanding of the underlying themes being represented. Make responsible memes, m'kay?

Comment: The moment i saw that "I hate chimichangas", first thing came to mind was "But you already do. " Huh, flawed meme, but made for a good reason :)

Comment: On seeing this, I first though deadpool was subverting the meme itself -- within the meme.

Comment: That would be consistent with his inconsistency.

Comment: Disagree.  Deadpool being Deadpool, he's aware of his presence in the meme and is deliberately subverting it.

Comment: Where is the pancake one from?

Answer (score 14):

What hasn't yet been addressed is that chimichanga is featured in the recent *Deadpool* film, and in that canon there's no concept of him not liking them. It's obvious that the references in the movie were built on the running joke from the comics, but it's a fair guess that only a small percentage of the people who've spent [3/4 of a billion USD](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl2588706305/) would be familiar with the panels provided in other answers.

Due to the enormous popularity of the film, and the chimichanga references throughout, I would guess that it was meant to appeal to not only Deadpool comic fans, but to fans of the movie (or *just* the movie).

See this exclusive postcard included in the special red-cased Blu-ray of the film, that people like myself received:

[image: Postcard with a yellows border with red chillis going around it; a star comes from the top left corner with the words "Greetings from Mexico", Deadpool stands over the background blocking most of it holding a chimichanga in his left hand on a plate and makes an OK sign with his right; the words say "How do you say Chimichanga" in Spanish?"]
<sup>Picture included so that my answer isn't the only one without them.</sup>

And finally, accurate or not, I think most people still don't give a damn.

Comment: But the Deadpool/chimichanga meme predates the movie by several years. [Example from 2013](http://zantyarz.deviantart.com/art/Deadpool-The-pony-with-a-mouth-402809019).

Comment: @jpmc26 Deadpool and chimichangas is very old, but the the Hail Hydra panel is *brand new* and the Deadpool movie caused a resurgence of popularity in Deadpool and Deadpool-related mouth noises.

Answer (score 10):

Out-of-canon, mentioning chimichangas has been an occasional running joke (although he's also generally more focused on food than a lot of other heroes, in keeping with his personality type which seems to be focused more on visceral experiences than brooding angst or intellectual pursuits, or a more even balance of all of these, like some heroes).

Canonically?  It's mostly about the sound of the word.

[image: Deadpool leaves Barat's loft and heads for a restaurant/cafe; he sits down and orders an enchilada from the waiter; he says to himself that he doesn't really like eating chimichangas but likes saying it chimichangas]

Which makes that meme joke in the question somewhat out of place.